# Z3 : Encoding functions whose ranges are set of subsets

Tags: z3

I would like to ask how I can encode functions whose ranges are set of subsets.

For example, I have a set Proc = {1, 2, 3} and a set Number = {4, 5, 6}. And now I would like to declare a function "fcn" from Proc to a set of subsets of Number. I intend to use 8 variables for each subsets of Number by declaring:

```
    (declare-fun var1 (Int) Bool) 
    (assert (= (var1 4) true)) 
    (assert (= (var1 5) true)) 
    (assert (= (var1 6) true))

    ...

    (declare-fun var8 (Int) Bool) 
    (assert (= (var8 4) false)) 
    (assert (= (var8 5) false)) 
    (assert (= (var8 6) false))
```

I guess, "fcn" should be (declare-fun fcn (Int) ...). Unfortunately, I don't kown how to declare the range of "fcn".

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use arrays to encode sets (and sets of sets). A set of A is encoded as an (Array A Bool). So then a set of sets of A is (Array (Array A Bool) Bool).
You can add and remove elements from such sets using "store". You can take unions and intersections using the "map" function. 
See also, 
Generalized, Efficient Array Decision Procedures. Leonardo de Moura, Nikolaj Bjørner. FMCAD 2009. Extended version in MSR-TR-121.
http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/?id=102329

Comment: Thank you very much, Nikolaj.